# Bash syntax issue, 'syntax error: unexpected "do" (expecting "fi")'

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, docker, sh

I have a sh script that I am using on Windows and Mac/Linux machines, and seems to work with no issues normally.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$jmxname" ]
then
cd ./tests/Performance/JMX/ || exit

echo "-- JMX LIST --"

# set the prompt used by select, replacing "#?"
PS3="Use number to select a file or 'stop' to cancel: "

# allow the user to choose a file
select jmxname in *.jmx
do
    # leave the loop if the user says 'stop'
    if [[ "$REPLY" == stop ]]; then break; fi

    # complain if no file was selected, and loop to ask again
    if [[ "$jmxname" == "" ]]
    then
        echo "'$REPLY' is not a valid number"
        continue
    fi

    # now we can use the selected file, trying to get it to run the shell script
    rm -rf ../../Performance/results/* && cd ../jmeter/bin/ && java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -n -t ../../JMX/"$jmxname" -l ../../results/"$jmxname"-reslut.jtl -e -o ../../results/HTML
    # it'll ask for another unless we leave the loop
    break
done
else
    cd ./tests/Performance/JMX/ && rm -rf ../../Performance/results/* && cd ../jmeter/bin/ && java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -n -t ../../JMX/"$jmxname" -l ../../results/"$jmxname"-reslut.jtl -e -o ../../results/HTML
fi
```

I am now trying to do some stuff with a Docker container and have used a node:alpine image, as the rest of my project is NodeJS based, but for some reason the script will not run in the Docker container giving the following -

```
line 12: syntax error: unexpected "do" (expecting "fi")
```

How can I fix that? The script seems to be working for every system it's been run on so far, and not thrown up any issues.

Comment: how you start the script ?

Comment: via an npm command "sh node_modules/ukri-test-framework/scripts/runPerformance.sh"

Comment: do and done make sense with `while` or `for` loop in shell scripts

Comment: i think that has something to do with POSIX sh, since it is a bash syntax

Comment: it just seems strange that it has worked on all windows/mac/linux machines ive used so far, but now having issues in the docker container...

Comment: and you run it there also with sh ?

Comment: @fly2matrix : In `bash`, `select` does have a `do`. In POSIX shell, there is no `select`, so it should already reported the `select` line itself as error. Since the script is invoked via `sh`, we would need to know what `sh` is linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the script is executed as '/bin/sh', and not as /bin/bash. You can see the message with '/bin/sh -n script.sh'

Check how the script is invoked. On different systems /bin/sh is symlinked to bash or other shell that is less feature rich.

In particular, the problem is with the `select` statement, included in bash, but not part of the POSIX standard.

Another option is that bash on your docker is set to be POSIX compliant by default

Comment: Ah, this could make sense, I can't connect to the container with /bin/bash only /bin/sh will look into this a bit more as this will get my answer i think...thanks mate

Comment: A little more detail: POSIX *allows*, but does not *require*, `select` to be treated as a reserved word. Here, the shell parses it as just another command name. Thus, it is a surprise to the parser to see `do` without having seen `for`, `while`, or `until` yet.

Answer (score 0):

@dash-o was correct, and adding -

```
RUN apk update && apk add bash
```

to my dockerfile added bash into the container and now it works fine :)